# grails session creation, on how to prevent it

Tags: session, grails, session-variables

in the last line in the following bug report

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/5296

it is stated that;

`In an ideal world, it would be possible to turn off HttpSession creation for a whole Controller (all actions) and also turn them off for a particular set of actions.`

This is however, a quite old bugreport, so my question is:

is this possible in an upcoming or todays version (1.3.7) of grails? If not, shouldn't it be?

The reason i seek this kind of behavior is due to development of RESTful API's in grails, where the very nature of REST is **stateless**.

Comment: As far as the source for Grails tells the Session is only created when it's accessed and doesn't exist. Are you seeing otherwise?

Comment: Yes, when using in conjunction with acegi (have not upgraded to spring-security yet). But i will have to test this out further.

Comment: The issue then is acegi is creating a session to track authorization. If you upgrade to Spring Security you will have the ability to turn off the session filter/interceptor for a specific URL pattern. I don't know if that's possible in acegi or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grails does not create a session if you do not access the implicit *session* object or use session-scoped services. We have multiple projects running in production, where we do not use sessions. As long as you don't access those objects, you won't see any sessions (no JSESSIONID cookies being sent with the response).

Comment: Hm, thats good to hear. I was under the impression that it always created a session object. Maybe it is because im using an authentication mechanism like acegi/spring-security which forces this on authenticated http communication.

Comment: Yes, Spring Security does use the session (to store the UserDetails, I think)

Comment: Correct, but you can also turn that off by removing the filter from the chain for a specific URL pattern (e.g. /api/**).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need! Will you provide more details on how to disable sessions in spring security when using Grails?