# Configuring different timeout values for the same webapp

Tags: tomcat, session-timeout

I have a (grails) web-app with 2 url-patterns:

```
/web/**

/rest-api/**
```

The 1st one is used for plain-old web-user access and should be using the http-session with a timeout of 30 min.
The 2nd one is used by REST interfaces and shall contain no session at all (timeout=0).

Is it possible to set the tomcat up, to support both cases within the same webapp, or should I split it (the later is not funny)?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to override the session timeout programmatically. In a java servlet it is done like this:

```
request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(30);
```

So you could use the default web.xml value for one of your services and set it programmatically for the other.

Note also that Tomcat will not create an HttpSession unless some code is accessing it (usually through a call to `request.getSession()`). So the best way to not have a session is to not access it at all. However this can be hard to achieve if you are using some 3rd party libraries that are accessing the session behind your back.

Comment: so, if grails' dispatcher doesn't call any methods on httpSession, the later one should not be created. The question is if it's really the case? :)

Comment: never mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348731/grails-session-creation-on-how-to-prevent-it